# hi every one i'm just getting this error:failed to connect to 255.255.255.255: network is unreachable

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, sdk

1. I’m just using facebook php sdk v3.2.3
2. error type : curl exception…
3. I just use host with curl but it doesnt work…

Here is my code:

```
  <?php 
  require 'facebook.php';
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '',
    'secret' => ''
 ));
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Facebook PHP</title>
</hea    <body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<?php
//get user from facebook object
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user): //check for existing user id
 try {

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
    // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
    // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
    // just ask the user to login again here.
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

     echo '<p>getType: ',$e->getType(), '</p>';;
    echo '<p>getMessage: ',$e->getMessage(), '</p>';;
  }  

    echo '<p>User ID: ', $user, '</p>';

    //print logout link
    echo '<p><a href="logout.php">logout</a></p>';
     else: //user doesn't exist
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'diplay'=>'popup',
        'scope'=>'email',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/blabla'
       ));
        echo '<p><a href="', $loginUrl, '" target="_top">login</a></p>';
     endif; //check for user id
       ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please...can anyone face this issue befor....please help if u solve this...

Comment: The IP 255.255.255.255 is the broadcast address of network 0.0.0.0 (this network) and can't be assigned to a single node.

Comment: Is your server's DNS and outbound network connection setup properly?

Comment: the line :echo '<p>User ID: ', $user, '</p>'; is working fine and return proper userID....it seems just the graph api doesn't work..any idea???????

Comment: @Igy : is any special config needed to be set on my host ? i just use a free host that support curl function.....

Answer (score 0):

Just a few modifications will solve it, I GUESS (Guess, as I don't still see the facebook.php)

```
<?php 
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => '', 'secret' => ''));
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Facebook PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<?php
//get user from facebook object
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user): //check for existing user id
 try {

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
    // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
    // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
    // just ask the user to login again here.
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    echo '<p>getType: ',$e->getType(), '</p>';;
    echo '<p>getMessage: ',$e->getMessage(), '</p>';;
  }  

    echo '<p>User ID: ', $user, '</p>';

    //print logout link
    echo '<p><a href="logout.php">logout</a></p>';
     else: //user doesn't exist
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'diplay'=>'popup',
        'scope'=>'email',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/blabla'
       ));
        echo '<p><a href="', $loginUrl, '" target="_top">login</a></p>';
     endif; //check for user id
      ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Let's see what will happen, we are tuned here, keep in touch.